# How to slow down https migration on my wordpress?

Tags: web, loading

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/ab-anmyna.my/HYNp6pBB

My https migration takes almost 3 second which is very serious. I cant think of a way to reduce the number. Tried CDN and stackflare

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. The SSL connection looks fine? But the response time it looks like on the data retrieved is quite slow, I don't believe it is related to https [WebpageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180804_37_d229d303301192392c5319a79a220b6c/)